# SSH into windows making multiple user sessions

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-desktop

I'm running into a bit of wall in my attempts to run some scripts on a remote ec2 windows box. I have few python scripts that run some selenium tests that involves automatically opening browsers. However, when I run this script via ssh, these browsers' GUI never show up, though I can clearly see them in the process list when I rdp into it.
In Remote Desktop Services Manager, I see the user is the same, which is correct, however the session is different. The processes in my RDP sessions are labelled RDP-Tcp#0 and the processes run through SSH are labelled with Services.
Is there anyway to either collapse User sessions, switch between whichever I'm viewing, or select which Session to send commands to?

Currently, the ssh command I'm using is simply:
ssh -i key user@host "python run_python_script.py"

Comment: I'd check the ssh server's setup. ssh isn't a "native" windows protocol, so I'm not surprised that internally it's not redirected/repriviliged/etc... the same way RDP is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't quite sure how to solve that problem directly, but instead, I ran the ssh daemon from that user account. Since it's then a child of explorer.exe, all windows opened show up there properly.